# Die weibliche Form des A-Worts

Tags: usage, insult, gender-neutrality

Ich finde es toll, dass es im Deutschen männliche und weibliche Berufsbezeichungen gibt (z. B. *ein König - eine Königin, ein Biograf - eine Biografin, ein Kanzler - eine Kanzlerin* usw.). Genauso wie im Russischen (meine Muttersprache).
Ich bin der Meinung, dass diese Trennung sehr schön und phonetisch logisch ist (im Vergleich zu Englisch, wo *a teacher* einen Mann oder eine Frau bezeichnen kann).

Dazu habe ich eine Frage:

Wenn ein Mann sich schlecht benimmt oder Unsinn sagt, ist er ein Arschloch.
Wird dann eine Frau *Arschlochin* genannt?

Comment: ich möchte an dieser Stelle noch hinzufügen dass jemand noch nicht direkt ein Arschloch ist, nur weil er Unsinn redet :) Arschloch ist schon eine heftige Beschimpfung - чайник :-)

Comment: @Alex, ich dachte, dass A-Wort eine starke Demütigung ist. Oder? Чайник ist nur ein funny professionellen Klischee für die, die in einem Bereich nicht erfahrlich sind. z.B. _da ich nur Deutsch lerne, bin ich ein чайник deswegen_ oder _sie fährt mit dem Auto wie ein чайник_. Das tut nicht weh. Aber A-Wort ist etwas anderes ;)

Comment: ich wollte чайник auch nicht in Relation zu Arschloch setzen :) Mein Russisch ist noch sehr am Anfang :-) A-loch ist keine Demütigung per-se, es ist tatsächlich eine mittlere bis starke Beleidigung, je nach Betonung und Kontext.

Comment: Der Eindruck vom Deutschen ist nicht ganz richtig. König/Kanzler/Biograf sind grammatikalisch männliche Formen, bezeichnen aber nicht notwendig Männer - nur umgekehrt gilt, dass wenn Du Männer bezeichnen willst, die männliche Form benutzt werden muss. Dies allein markiert die Person aber keineswegs als männlich. Das kann sich aus dem Kontext ergeben (der Vorname ist gefallen) oder es muss explizit dazu gesagt werden. Dagegen bezeichnen weibliche Formen fast immer exklusiv Frauen (Königin, Kanzlerin, Biografin), Ausnahmen: die Fachkraft, die Person, die Katze, die Schlange, ... .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Das* Loch ist sächlich, daher ist auch jedes Kompositum, das mit diesem Wort endet (wie eben *das* Arschloch), sächlich.

Der Eindruck, *Arschloch* z.B. in dem Satz

> Dieser Mann ist *ein Arschloch*.

wäre männlich, kommt davon, dass der unbestimmte Artikel *ein* sowohl männliche, als auch sächliche Wörter bezeichnet:

> männlich: der Wagen, ein Wagen.
>   sächlich: das Auto, ein Auto.
>   weiblich: die Karre, eine Karre.

Wie das letzte Beispiel zeigt, ist das bei weiblichen Wörtern nicht der Fall.

Wenn in einem Satz der Form

> A ist B

A und B gleichgesetzt werden, hat das keinen Einfluss auf das grammatikalische Geschlecht von A und B.

Nur bei Berufen und Begriffen, die ähnlich wie Berufe verwendet werden (z.B. Diabetiker, Deutscher), gibt es jeweils eine männliche und eine weibliche Form, niemals aber eine sächliche Variante. Wie das Beispiel »*der Deutsche*« <-> »*die Deutsche*« zeigt, können die beiden Formen auch gleich sein, und sich tatsächlich nur im Geschlecht unterscheiden.

»Arschloch« ist weder ein Beruf, noch gehört es zu den Begriffen, die wie Berufe verwendet werden.

Comment: Ich widerspreche. Der Eindruck von Männlichkeit im Beispielsatz kommt aus der Semantik. Weil es da steht, dass es ein Mann ist. Bei "Diese Frau ist ein Sonnenschein" läutet so wenig eine grammatische Alarmglocke wie bei Arschloch, und zwar weil die Sprache das Geschlecht von Wörtern behandelt, immer behandelt, und nicht das Geschlecht von Personen.

Answer (score 1):

Unabhängig von der Schönheit (oder Hässlichkeit) des Ausdrucks oder seiner Bedeutungen …

Einige Menschen haben die Bestrebung für alles und jede (sic!) eine feminine Form – in diesem Fall besser: eine *weibliche* Form – zu erfinden. Und das geht wunderbar, indem man an das Wort ein *-in* anhängt – gegebenenfalls mit Umlaut, also in diesem Fall *Arschlöchin*.

Im Plural müsste aus der *Arschlöchin* korrekt *die Arschlöchinnen* werden. Aber andererseits existiert belegt auch die Form *Arschlöcherinnen*:

> Angeklagt war die 56-jährige Hannelore Mabry, Chefin der Zeitschrift „Der Feminist“. Sie hatte, so die Anklage, auf einer Gewerkschafts-Tagung „DGB-Huren“ einfach „Arschlöcher“ genannt.
>
> Der Amtsrichter, der mit Nachnamen auch noch Anke hieß, fragte die Angeklagte: „Finden Sie es richtig, andere Frauen als Arschlöcher zu bezeichnen?”
>
> Die Kämpferin für die Rechte der Frauen entgegnete: „Erstens mache ich keinen Unterschied zwischen Frauen und Männern; zweitens muss in manchen Fällen etwas im Interesse der Öffentlichkeit deutlich gesagt werden; und drittens habe ich nicht Arschlöcher, sondern **Arschlöcherinnen** gesagt.“

(zitiert nach [Das neue Handbuch des Journalismus; Blogeintrag vom 1. Juli 2012](http://www.journalismus-handbuch.de/die-weibliche-form-des-arschlochs-friedhof-der-worter-1314.html); Hervorhebung von mir)

Comment: Wie ist das dann beim Arsch? Wird das zur Ärschin? Und wenn man eine Gruppe anspricht "Ihr Ärschinnen und Ärsche"?

Comment: @PaulFrost War nicht Teil der Frage, ich würde aber tatsächlich von der Ärschin sprechen.

Answer (score -1):

Die phonologisch richtige, aber nur scherzhaft mögliche, weibliche Form zu *Loch* ist nicht *Lochin*, sondern *Löchin*. Es ist zu beachten, dass sich dabei auch die Aussprache des *ch* ändert.

Comment: Wieso ist das so?

Comment: Wenn *Löchin* die weibliche Form sein soll, wie lautet dann die männliche? Denn **das** Loch ist nicht männlich sondern sächlich. Und wie lauten dann die weiblichen Formen von *Boot*, *Tuch*, *Salz*, usw.?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, die Bootin, Tüchin, Sälzin.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Die männlichen Formen dieser sächlichen Wörter bist du mir komplett schuldig geblieben, und die weiblichen halte ich für rein willkürliche Wortschöpfungen die ebenso unsinnig sind wie Lochin oder Löchin.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, echt jetzt, die sind unsinnig? Dann ist es wohl besser, sie nur im Scherz zu benutzen. Vielleicht sollte ich das Wort „scherzhaft“ in meine Antwort einfügen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Dann erkläre mir doch bitte, warum *Lochin* nicht scherzhaft benutzt werden kann, während deiner Meinung nach der Gebrauch von *Löchin* phonologisch richtig sein soll. Und gib bitte auch bekannt, welche scherzhaft verwendbaren männliche Formen von *Loch, Boot, Tuch* und *Salz* phonologisch richtig sein sollen.

Comment: Das Loch, der Locher. Das Boot, der Boote. Das Tuch, der Tusch. Das Salz, der Salsa.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that we received some flags on comments to this post citing rudeness. The flagged comments have been deleted.
This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to act in a professional and civil tone when using this site. [Be nice.](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) Focus on the post, not the person. Rudeness and belittling language are not acceptable.
If you see behaviour that is rude, offensive, or otherwise inappropriate for the site, please do not respond in kind; simply flag the content and move on.